# Get a data out of a function

Tags: node.js, bitcoin

I'm new on Stackoverflow as a member. So I'm sorry if I don't know yet how to put the code in the design you do :s

I tried all night to find a way to make the deposit Bitcoin Key out of the `client.initWallet('***', '***', function(err, wallet)` function.

The `console.log(address)` you see downstairs is working fine. But juste after the `}`, I cannont access the data. I really don't know what to do. If someone has any idea why I can't keep the value on "`address`" ...

Thanks for your time :D

```
const key = '*key*';
const secret = '*secretkey*';

blocktrail = require('blocktrail-sdk');

client = blocktrail.BlocktrailSDK({
    apiKey: key,
    apiSecret: secret,
    network: 'BTC',
    testnet: false
});


client.initWallet('*user*', '*password*',
    function(err, wallet) {
    wallet.getNewAddress(function (err, address) {
      **console.log(address);**
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bluebird can convert your callback functions to function which returns Promise,

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const key = '*key*';
const secret = '*secretkey*';

async function getWallet(){
    blocktrail = require('blocktrail-sdk');
    client = blocktrail.BlocktrailSDK({
        apiKey: key,
        apiSecret: secret,
        network: 'BTC',
        testnet: false
    });

    var asyncInitWallet = bluebird.promisify(client.initWallet);
    var wallet = await asyncInitWallet('*user*', '*password*');

    var asyncGetNewAddress = bluebird.promisify(wallet.getNewAddress);
    var address = await asyncGetNewAddress();
    console.log('address: ', address);
}
getWallet();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answering. I try your code and I find that on my console :

(node:89482) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async functionwithout a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:89482) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I'm not sure there is an easy answer :s..

Comment: Yeah obviously, You need to keep await statements inside try/catch block, I just gave you an idea about how you can use promise to solve this. Inside catch block log the error to identify whats the error